# Visual SourceSafe and VS2005 Without Full Integration

Tags: visual-studio-2005, controls, version, visual-sourcesafe

Is it possible to use VSS 2005 with VS2005 and not have the .sln and proj files included in the source repository?  If so could somebody please provide a template for getting this working.  It strikes me, that understanding of the project hierarchy would be a damned site simpler without the default integration between VS2005 and VSS.  And before anybody comments, the choice of source control is dictated by the client not me... more's the pity:-(

Kind Regards

Paul J.

Comment: Why would you want the sln and proj excluded from SCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSS integrates at the Solution-Project level or at a file level.

If you want integration with Visual Studio, you have to use Solution-Project level integration.

If you are willing to forego Visual Studio integration, you can simply put the files into VSS and manually check-in/check-out as required.

Answer (score 1):

The `.sln` and `.prj` files dictate what files belong to what projects, where they are, what compiler flags to use to build them, etc. Those most definitely **need to be controlled**.

Not controlling them would be like not controlling your makefile. Five years from now, when all you can find is the repository, how is anybody going to be able to build the system?

If you are really aching to not use them (perhaps you have your own real `makefile` you use to build?) then probably the best thing to do is to use VSS directly to pull down the system. IOW: Don't use the integration. Of course, if you aren't using VisualStudio for source control integration and you aren't using to compile, that doesn't leave a whole lot of reason to be using it at all. Emacs is a far better editor, so just use it instead and be done with VS entirely.